# setcenter issue with google maps with rails 6 and webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, webpacker

I'm pretty new to rails + webpacker and I'm trying to show a marker on a map. It works well for multiple markers, but when there is only one, it shows the middle of the ocean. When I refresh, it works perfectly.I'm using Rails 6.

Here is the plugin :

```js
import GMaps from 'gmaps/gmaps.js';

const initMap = () => {
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    const initMap = document.getElementById('map');

      if (initMap) { // don't try to build a map if there's no div#map to inject in
        const map = new GMaps({ el: '#map', lat: 0 , lng: 0 });
        const markers = JSON.parse(initMap.dataset.markers);
        map.addMarkers(markers);

      if (markers.length === 0) {
        map.setZoom(2);
      } else if (markers.length === 1) {
        map.setCenter(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng);
        map.setZoom(12);
      } else {
        map.fitLatLngBounds(markers);
      }
    };
  });
}
export { initMap };
```

Here is the `application.js`

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

// External imports
import { initMap } from '../plugins/init_map';
import { initAutocomplete } from '../plugins/init_autocomplete';
import "bootstrap";
import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
initMap();

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {

  initAutocomplete();
  flatpickr("#booking_start_time", {
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
  });
  flatpickr("#booking_end_time", {
      enableTime: true,
      dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
    });
});
```

thanks !

Comment: Did you try do move `initMap()` into `turbolinks:load` callback ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `div id="map"` on your HTML files?
First, you should check if the HTML is rendered BEFORE your Javascript loading, I think it's the case but I remember having **caching issues like this with Turbolinks**.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks)

> During rendering, Turbolinks replaces the current  element outright and merges the contents of the  element. The JavaScript window and document objects, and the HTML  element, persist from one rendering to the next.

Try to remove your `"turbolinks:load"` declarations.

After that, you should try do add `debugger` on every step of your script like

```js
  debugger;
  const markers = JSON.parse(initMap.dataset.markers);
```

And debug it with Chrome to check if the data are loaded or not